# Css rule doesn't operate

Tags: html, css

in my website I'm changing color font in a selector but it still remain the same old color. I don't understand the reason beacause the other rule in the same selector works correctly.

This is the website: http://debatoversigt.dk/

I'm triyng to change color in this selector, because I need to have yellow font in left item menu when is selected:

```
.selected{
background-image: url('../images/left_menu_hover.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% auto;
color:yellow!important;
}
```

I've added this other rule but doesn't work on color,but ad example works on background:

```
.art-block  li:hover , .art-block  li:visited
{
color:red !important;
}
```

Comment: Please do not link to your web site. Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 2):

Your .selected css is being overwridden by the css cascade:

```
.art-blockcontent * {
    color: #666 !important;
}
```

has a higher specificity than

```
.selected {
    color: #FF0 !important;
}
```

so it is "winning"

try to change your .selected style to:

```
#art-main .selected {
    color: #FF0 !important;
}
```

the additional id used will increase the specificity of you css rule and cause it to "win", read more about css specificity: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: I've used your suggestion but doesn't work...now seem it win by firebug but the font is not yellow

Comment: You need a space `color: #FF0 !important;`

Answer (score 0):

Your headers are links, so simply changing the color won't work.

```
.selected a:link, .selected a:visited {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: yellow;
}
```

Try something like that.